# Ocupação de espaço anormalmente grande

Tags: sql-server

#### Ambiente:

- Windows Server 2008 (A: x64, B: x86)
- SQL Server 2008R2 em ambos.

A segunda coluna é o número de linhas, a terceira coluna é o espaço ocupado em KB.

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que possa estar a provocar isto? (Eu já esgotei as ideias... )

[image: Imagem]

Comment: Por dizer o que é cada coluna?

Comment: Onde trabalho, já tivemos alguma dificuldade de muito espaço sendo ocupado por um processo de muita deleção e escrita em uma mesma tabela. Ela não era uma tabela carregada de significado para o usuário final (era usada para detectar mudanças no banco para sincronizar bases), então remodelamos o sistema para não precisarmos mais dela

Comment: Jefferson as colunas são: nome_tabela, numero_linhas, espaço_ocupado

Comment: O problema é que em um dos servidores com bastantes mais registos está a ocupar imensamente menos espaço.

Comment: Os tipos de dados são exatamente iguais? Se executar um `datalength` nos campos texto, eles terão os mesmos tamanhos? Mesmo num campo `varchar` é possível ter espaços em branco no final até completar o tamanho total.

Comment: Como está a estrutura do banco de dados? Possuí DER?